# Python Pandas: Find a pattern in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Dataframe (1,2 millon rows):

```
df_test_2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["end","beginn","end","end","beginn","beginn","end","end","end","beginn","end"],"B":[1,10,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,111,112]})`
```

Now I try to find a sequences. Each "beginn "should match the first "end"where the distance based on column B is at least 40 
occur.
For the provided Dataframe that would mean: 
[image]

The sould problem is that 
Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output? Indexes? What have you tried/investigated and why didn't that fulfill your requirements?

Comment: Is there only begin and end in the dataframe or something else? Should extra begin/end entries be ignored? Please post what you have tried already

Comment: Group number 2 only has a distance of 20, something is wrong with your example.

Comment: To be honest I am absolutley absolutely clueless.  That is a part of an project which is due today and I have been working for around 12 h (Programming the UI etc.) . ^^therefore my head is prety empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that as your output you want a list of sequences with the starting and ending value. The second sequence that you identify in your picture has a distance lower to 40, so I also assumed that that was an error.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import namedtuple
df_test_2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["end","beginn","end","end","beginn","beginn","end","end","end","beginn","end"],"B":[1,10,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,111,112]})

sequence_list = []
Sequence = namedtuple('Sequence', ['beginn', 'end'])

beginn_flag = False
beginn_value = 0
for i, row in df_test_2.iterrows():
    state = row['A']
    value = row['B']

    if not beginn_flag and state == 'beginn':
        beginn_flag = True
        beginn_value = value 
    elif beginn_flag and state == 'end':
        if value >= beginn_value + 40:
            new_seq = Sequence(beginn_value, value)
            sequence_list.append(new_seq)
            beginn_flag = False

 print(sequence_list)
```

This code outputs the following:

```
[Sequence(beginn=10, end=50), Sequence(beginn=70, end=110)]
```

Two sequences, one starting at 10 and ending at 50 and the other one starting at 70 and ending at 110.

Comment: That is amazing. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Beside of the solution for my problem, I learned new  a type "namedtuple"

Comment: Yeah, named tuples are great for creating a quick printable object: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple. 

Later on you can call its attribute like a class. Example:
```new_seq = Sequence(beginn=10, end=50)
print(new_seq.beginn)```